# robot model does not appear in rviz melodic

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to bring my [robot model](https://github.com/tik0/amiro_robot) (which I have developed for kinetic) to work under melodic.
Everything works so far (despite some plugin issues where I have already committed a pull request), but not the visualization of the robot model.
The xacro description of the robot is [here](https://github.com/tik0/amiro_robot/blob/master/amiro_description/urdf/amiro.xacro).

rviz visualization under melodic:
[image: rviz visualization under melodic]

rviz visualization under kinetic:
[image: rviz visualization under kinetic]

Here are some points which I have investigated already:

- I've checked the model on the parameter server via `rosparam get /amiro1/robot_description` under kinetic and melodic and **they are identical**.
- The **dae model is also valid**, because rviz complains when I just manipulate the mesh location.
- The wired thing is, that the hokuyo dae mesh is visualized under melodic.
- I also check all rviz debug messages via `rqt_logger_level` and rviz tells me that the URDF description is loaded correctly.
- Maybe it is realted to this [issue](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1249) but again, the hokuyo dae is shown, but not my robot.

**If one would like to test it, follow these steps:**

1. checkout https://github.com/tik0/amiro_robot.git
2. checkout https://github.com/tik0/amiro_msgs.git
3. build and run `roslaunch amiro_gazebo amiro_simple_world.launch`

**Can anyone help me with this issue?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296227/robot-model-does-not-appear-in-rviz-melodic/) by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Other rviz users have encountered a similar issue at https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1249. The solution may be related to your locales.

If that's the underlying issue, modifying the following environment variable will fix it for you:

`export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-08-28**:
Setting this variable solved the issue indeed, thanks.

**Comment by [girayuzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/24517/girayuzun/) on 2019-10-25**:
that worked, thx
If you want to make it in system;

echo 'LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/locale